# Load exact font win32

Tags: winapi, fonts

How do I force the Win32 GDI font mapper to only load a font whose font name has an exact match? I am loading specific fonts, for which there are NO viable substitutions. Any substitution at all is incorrect. I want the the CreateFont or CreateFontIndirect to actually fail. Or, perhaps some other Win32 interface that gives more control. Even if I load a font resource from a file, it will still try to substitute. And, there doesn't seem to be a way of getting the font name from the resource.

Comment: I don't know whether there is any way to control GDI's font mapper, though you could probably emulate the desired behavior by first looking for the specific font using [EnumFontFamiliesEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-enumfontfamiliesexw).

Comment: I think the design assumption in GDI is that there must always be _some_ font selected into a device context. The suggestion to first enumerate and look for the specific font makes sense. You could also use [GetFontData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getfontdata) to inspect the 'name' table of the font that is actually selected into the DC to confirm it's what you want.

Comment: So far, using GetFontData is the best approach -- but only when I know the face name. Loading a font resource from a font file does not give me that information. In order to try to force the GDI mapper to only select the requested font, getting the best LOGFONT options is also important. I created one of the fonts, and I can't predict exactly what it wants. For example, the charset option. This has no real relationship to the font at all. I am guessing that the default ANSI_CHARSET is the best choice. All of these fonts are Unicode fonts, yet there is no matching charset option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, part of the problem was mine in that this was old 32-bit ANSI code converted to 64-bit Unicode some time in the past. So the routine which specified the font name only copied half of the name, but the nul-terminator was correct, leaving half of the font name as garbage. Fixing that, went a long way to fixing the problems.

Second the GetTextMetrics function does not work for fonts installed as resources, so that function is not usable. Additionally, the GetFontData only works for True Type fonts, so it wasn't usable either. All of the fonts of interest are Unicode, but not all are True Type. However, the GetTextFace function does work. Also, even though extended font information is returned from font enumeration, setting the full font name was pointless since it is not actually in LOGFONT.

After examining the LOGFONT attributes to determine the most significant, I settled on the face name, the ANSI character set and setting the font family to don't care. The weight, italic, underline and struck out attributes are apparently fudged when necessary. Defaults for the remaining attributes appear to be acceptable and are not generally required.

After the font was loaded, I called GetTextFace name and compared that to the requested font. That appears to work well.

Comment: Hi, @Michael, you could also feel free to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)